# Image content from Accessibility Service Android

Tags: android, kotlin, service, accessibilityservice

I want to read image or video content from YouTube App or any App using this Accessibility Service. Is there any way i can do or any API which provide this information? I am able to read all the text displays on the screen. I have searched out but couldn't find any suitable solution.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks